# spring cloud dataflow kubernetes deployment pass property

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I have spring cloud dataflow app running in kubernetes . Now  i need to pass new property like template metadata label enableIdentityHelper as part to stream deployment .Below is the deployment yaml which works standalone as below

**DEPLOYMENT YAML**

```
 kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: customapp
      labels:
        app: customapp
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: customapp
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: customapp
            enableIdentityHelper: "true"
        spec:
          securityContext:
          runAsUser: 99
          fsGroup: 99
```

Now i need to have this passed these properties (like enableIdentityHelper,runAsUser,fsGroup etc)as part of stream creation. Does stream support this ? If so is it something like below ?

```
   deployer.client.kubernetes.template.metadata.labels.enableIdentityHelper=true
   deployer.client.kubernetes.template.spec.securityContext.runAsUser=99
   deployer.client.kubernetes.template.spec.securityContext.fsGroup=99
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the deployment properties in the form of `deployer.<app-name>.kubernetes.<property-name>`. Kubernetes app deployer used by SCDF uses a list of deployment properties. In your case, you need to pass like this:

```
deployer.<app>.kubernetes.deploymentLabels=myLabelName:myLabelValue
```

You can refer the documentation on how to pass the deployment label [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_deployment_labels) and the pod security context [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_pod_security_context)